# jQuery animate resizing

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm struggling with the animate resizing function.

I have a card game, where some cards have a different size and I want to move and resize some cards.

I would like to do something like that:

```
$(from).animate({width:$(to).width(), height:$(to).height()}, 2000);
```

This should resize the element to the size of the other element, but it just fades out, although the height and the width are def not 0.

Any ideas, how to make that work? I'm a bit confused.

Best regards

Comment: Might be because `.width()` gives values without `px`. Try `... width: $(to).width() + 'px' ... `

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "to" is a class or id. If it is id then give `$("#to").width()` ,if it is a class then give `$(".to").width()`."to" is not a component.I guess thatz why it takes width and height as "0" and fading out!!

Working [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waNVEX)

Comment: That's not the problem. to and from are just strings, which represents the id or the class.

Comment: oh k mathew..did you check that link??